# How to implement something similar to Stack Overflows Tag's widgets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In Stack Overflow, have noticed that once one is done writing an post and starts entering in specific tags inside the Tags text field , that the text of the tags becomes a cool little widget which is deletable via the X button (located on this widget).

May I ask if there is a popular 3rd party library that one can use to emulate this same situation ? 
That someone types something into a text field and the individual words inside the text field becomes turned into some ui element with an X on it ?

Otherwise, how can someone code a mechanism like this him / herself ? 
What type of CSS/HTML/JavaScript be needed ? Are these visual tags `<div>`s?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Textboxlist](http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/).

Comment: If the list elements were just draggable (i.e.similar to jquery UI sortable). . . that would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ will transform your everyday `<select>` and `<option>` elements into this format. plus no license fee (although I wouldn't argue TextboxList's $20 fee is unreasonable)

Comment: Thanks qntmfred, I've been playing around with "chosen", but can't seem to get it to work with my text field. My code is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/bNDHy/ Would appreciate it if you could help me.